# Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined in Angular Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a angular firestore project. In the service I have used get method to get data from the firebase and used a condition ' where ' but getting the error  **Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined** in dev tool. I want to get value of Info from the collection 'cn' based on cID. I have a model as well. I have used here abbreviations only

```
  getN(id:any){    
    return this.db 
    .collection('cn')
    .ref.where('cID','==', id)
    .get()  }
```

In the component I have

```
this.cService.getN(this.id).then(
    (c:any)  => {         
      this.dataSource.data = c.info;          
    }                
  )  ;
```

Comment: It seems like `this.id` is undefined when you call `getN`, and Firestore needs a real value to filter on. I recommend putting a breakpoint on the `this.cService.getN(this.id)` call and run in the debugger, to validate `this.id` is undefined, and then backtrack from there to see where you expected it to get its value from.

Comment: If you expect `id` to be a `number` or `string` then type that instead of `any` as `any` also accepts `undefined` in that way you will get meaningful errors like `undefined` is not assignable to type `number` or `string`.